# Additional fields in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 scaffolds Role(name:string), Permission(name:string) I created a relation between them. So now i can display Role's permissions in an easy way: Role.permissions.

The problem is to create a form for new Role, because in addition to the field 'name' I would like to add there a list of permissions (checkboxes).

This is what I managed to do so far. (Now I'm using a textbox instead of checkbox)

```
<%= form_for(@role)  do |f| %>
  <% if @role.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@role.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this role from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @role.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="list_of_fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= text_field_tag :myVariable] %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Precisely I'm talking about this piece of code:

```
  <div class="list_of_fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= text_field_tag :myVariable] %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This produces:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"MdS0VkLAxGoZM8P71H0a9M54CpMt8DnnwSp75UVGtqE=",
>   "role"= {"name"=>"abc"}, "myVariable"=>"xyz", "commit"=>"Create Role"}

I don't like this solution because if somebody chooses a specific name of permission it may  fail ('commit' e.g.).

I would like to close all these additional fields within a hash. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Railscast 189 - [embedded association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association). Ryan tackles exactly what you're looking to do here. It's a bit old and uses roles embedded in the user model, but you should be able to adapt it.

Additionally, you might consider using cancan for roles based permissions (railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan))